# React router not reload old component

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have this routes system

```
....
<Route  path="/:slug_1/:slug_2" name="component_2" component={component_2}/>
<Route  path="/:slug_1" name="component_1" component={component_1}/>
....
```

When loading a home page I click on a component_1 link by path `.../slug-1`
After I click a component_2 link by path `.../slug-1/slug-2`. But after this when I click a component_1 link and in URL it creates a path `.../slug-2/slug-1` but it must be path `.../slug-1` only

Please help me))

Answer (score 0):

Change the order and make **component_1** exact like this:

```
....
<Route exact path="/:slug_1" name="component_1" component={component_1}/>
<Route  path="/:slug_1/:slug_2" name="component_2" component={component_2}/>
....
```

With this if the user doesn't input a **slug_2** the route will go to **component_1**.

If there is a **slug_2** present it will go to **component_2**

Comment: Does not work. In the URL of the link (../slug-1), but when I clicked the link, the router it automatically redirects to the URL (... / slug-2 / slug-2)

Comment: @coding-scripting what's the link path? if the link path is something like

<Link to="/aslug" /> 

it should catch the component_1

Comment: links paths make in loop <Link to={slug} />, but after click rendered URL after old path

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the use of Switch and exact path

```
    import React from 'react';
    import {BrowserRouter, Route, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';

    import App from './App';
    import Component1 from './Component1';
    import Component2 from './Component2';

    const Router = () => (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/" component={App} />
          <Route exact path="/slug1" component={Component1} />
          <Route path="/slug1/:slug2" component={Component2} />
        </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );

    export default Router;
```

Your main file renders the Router component which can be used to navigate through the entire app

```
import React from 'react';
import { render, } from 'react-dom';
import Router from './components/Router';

render(<Router />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Yes, but I need slug_1 and slug_2 to be dynamic

Comment: @coding-scripting, I just replicated the issue and it works well using the code: 

    <Route path="/:about" component={About} />
    <Route path="/:about/:projects" component={Project} />


   <Link to="/about">About Me</Link>
   <Link to="/about/projects">Projects</Link>

Comment: links paths make in loop <Link to={slug} /> and not working router system